# fit x width boxes in y width box with z spacing between two boxes

Tags: geometry, functions

We only need one row and don't need to worry about heights and z is the horizontal spacing between two boxes

my first attempt was

$
\lfloor \frac{y}{x+z} \rfloor
$

but this fails since we don't need the space with the last box, example x=100, z=10, y=215, it will return 1 but the answer should be 2, any help?

Comment: Are you talking in one dimension?

Comment: yes, we only know the width of boxes

Comment: So what are you trying to calculate, exactly? Is it: how many boxes of width $x$ can you fit inside of a box of width $y$, when leaving a space of $z$ between each (smaller) box?

Comment: yes sir, and we don't need to consider the space with the last box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider what happens if you have $n$ smaller boxes. Then the total width required is (and let this sink in)
$$
nx+(n-1)z
$$
This is because you need one fewer spaces, than the amount of boxes.

Now the requirement is that this width should be smaller than $y$:
$$
nx+(n-1)z < y
$$
Now we are on the lookout for the largest integer value of $n$ that fulfills this condition. We can open the parentheses and move the terms around:
$$
nx+nz - z < y \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad  n(x+z)< y+z
$$
Now it's easy to solve for $n$:
$$
n = \left\lfloor \frac{y+z}{x+z} \right\rfloor
$$